# turn screen on and off with motion sensor

Tags: gpio, python, screen

I'm working on a project which will use a PIR motion sensor to turn on a connected HDMI monitor when there's someone in the room, and turn it off when they leave. I'm new to Linux, but not to Python. My code so far is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from subprocess import call

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
while true:
    i = GPIO.input(11)
    if i ==0:
        print("Screen off", i)
        call("vcgencmd display_power 0")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif i ==1:
        print("Screen on", i)
        call("vcgencmd display_power 1")
        time.sleep(30)
```

If I just type in `vcgencmd display_power 0` or `vcgencmd display_power 1` to a terminal, the commands work fine, but this script produces a

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'vcgencmd display_power 1'
```

I've found questions asking how to turn the screen on and off, and all of these seem to do it from the command line, not a Python script.

How can I run the command from the Python script?

Comment: I don't know python well, but does `call` take more than one argument? e.g., `call("vcgencmd", "display_power", "0")` - i.e. the first argument is the command, and the subsequent arguments are the command line parameters passed to the command

Comment: having looked, it could be `call(["vcgencmd", "display_power", "0"])` - it's very hard getting documentation for python for something like `call`!

Comment: I've tried both of those different commands; they both give the same error.

Comment: exactly the same error?

Comment: Di you try the the whole path `/usr/bin/vcgencmd` or using `Popen` rather than `call`?

Comment: @PiEnthusiast no I just called the function. Thanks for pointing that out; what would the syntax for that be? Like I said, I’m pretty new to Linux and I haven’t tried calling the command line with python before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @PiEnthusiast's and @Jaramonda's answers, I changed the calls to the function to read

```
call(["/usr/bin/vcgencmd", "display_power", "0"])
```

and it works great! I didn't understand how Linux terminal commands worked to be routed through Python scripts.

Comment: To do what you were originally attempting, you can just specify `shell=True` as an argument.  Also note that call() is considered a legacy API since Python 3.5.  The new run() method simplifies and harmonizes the API somewhat, and in this case it would just be `run('vcgencmd display_power 0', shell=True)` .

Comment: for me this just prints out "display_power=1" whether I call it with 1 or 0 and doesn't turn the screen on or off