# Fade screen on sleep and brighten on wake

Tags: python, screen, screen-saver

I'm looking for a way to control the screen brightness from code.
I saw [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87319/turn-screen-on-and-off-with-motion-sensor) but this just turns the screen on and off.
How can I dim the screen before it goes to sleep instead of just turning it off and wake up the screen in code (later using I/O) by brightening it gradually?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer to your question can probably be found in the answer to this [Adjusting the Brightness of the Official Touchscreen Display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46225/adjusting-the-brightness-of-the-official-touchscreen-display) post. I clearly says a display brightness can be adjusted by sending a value to /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness  as shown below.

```
echo n > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: sadly it doesn't work on the main display but only on the touchscreen. I don't even have /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight on my system...

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. BTW, there is an answer on the link above with a simple [Python script to module for controlling power and brightness of the official Raspberry Pi 7" touch display](http://github.com/linusg/rpi-backlight). It is for a touch display and perhaps you can download to give it a try to see if it can be used to adjust the brightness of your display.

Comment: If you look at the script file rpi_backlight.py you'll see right at the beginning that the PATH leads to non-other than "/sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/" - same thing sadly